# Is there a feature in PostgreSQL similar to Cassandra's keyspace?

Tags: postgresql, cassandra, multi-tenant

I'm weighing the options of moving a database from Cassandra to PostgreSQL. One significant hurdle is that our current, multi-tenant, Cassandra database utilizes keyspaces to segregate client data. Each client has an identical schema within their own dedicated keyspace. I'm not sure how, or if it is possible, to organize our data similarly in PostgreSQL?

Comment: I can't answer your PostgreSQL question, but have you thought about data modeling for multi-tenancy since the schemas are identical? something like PRIMARY KEY ((tenant_id, key), key2, key 3...)? Most multi tenant Cassandra deployments handle multi tenancy that way along side an authentication mechanism at the app layer. This obviously doesn't help if your customers require physically separated data. Just throwing it out there as an option :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE DATABASE keyspace_name
```

Key space is similar to database or table space in PostGres/Oracle/MySQL.